# Mongoose's populate() does not return data from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

I have the following Schema, and Base is the one-for-all collector of info:

```
const BaseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  creatorId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  users: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  messages: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Message" }]
});
```

And:

```
const BaseUserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: String },
  baseId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  acceptedMembership: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  isCreator: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

(I have one for `Message` which looks about the same)
The latter one is referred to as `User` in `const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);`
When I create a new Base I automatically add a user to a list within. In the DB i can see that the user does exist, but when I call the following the field does not  populate:

```
Base.find({ creatorId: req.params.id })
    .populate("users", "messages")
    .exec()
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

I get the following from the console.log:

```
[ { created: 2018-09-05T03:41:45.416Z,
    users: [],
    messages: [],
    _id: 5b8f508b2760c5329c13a9be,
    creatorId: 5b86f7970cd98b2004969bf0,
    title: 'testBase1',
    __v: 1 } ]
```

When I first create the base via React front-end, and the base gets added to a list, I see that the `users.length` is 1, or the length of the automatically created user. When I refresh the page, however, the userlist is empty in the console.

**Adding:**
Forget to show how I populate the userlist upon creation:

```
router.post("/add", jwtAuth, (req, res) => {
    Base.create({
        creatorId: req.body.userId,
        title: req.body.title
    }).then(baseInfo => {
        BaseUser.create({
            userId: req.body.username,
            baseId: baseInfo._id,
            created: Date.now(),
            acceptedMembership: true,
            isCreator: true
        })
            .then(baseuser => {
                baseInfo.users.push(baseuser);
                return baseInfo.save();
            })
            .then(base => res.json(base.serialize()));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**:

```
.populate("users", "messages")
```

to begin with will return `messages` from `users`. It has to be two separate entries, like so:

```
        .populate("users")
        .populate("messages")
```

Then, in the model

```
users: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
```

refers to the wrong `ref`. It has to be

```
users: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "BaseUser" }],
```

from

```
const BaseUser = mongoose.model("BaseUser", BaseUserSchema);
```

At last, I am not sure if this is needed, but I added a `ref` to each of the to-be-populated items:

```
baseId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "Base" },
baseId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Base" },
```

Now it works like a charm, all without additional `fetch`